# How do I to stop my Modal from showing every time I click on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently appending a Modal from my HTML into a TD. I currently have a function that will show the modal that was appended, however every time I click on the modal it runs the code for when I clicked on the TD (it is counting the modal as part of the TD) and therefore constantly showing the same modal.

I have tried:

```
      document.addEventListener("show", function(){
      $('td').off("click");
      });
```

And even:

```
 $(this).off("click",`#${modalId}`);
```

JavaScript

```
$('td').on('click', function(e) {

$('td').removeClass("selectedDate");
$(this).addClass("selectedDate");
var n = $(this).find('.date').text(); //selects the date input for the cell.
    let ordN = n + (n > 0 ? ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'][(n > 3 && n < 21) || n % 10 > 3 ? 0 : n % 10] : '');

let modal= $('.modal').clone(true);
$(this).append(modal);
let modalId= `${months[currentMonth]}-${n}-${currentYear}`;
modal.attr('id',`${modalId}`);


 $(this).find('#modalHeader').text(`${months[currentMonth]} ${ordN} ${currentYear}`);

 $(this).find(`#${modalId}`).show();
 document.addEventListener("show", function(){
   $('td').off("click");
  console.log('working')
 });
 console.log(this);
 $(this).off("click",`#${modalId}`);
 });
```

No matter where I look I can't seem to find a way to fix this issue ...

Comment: Can you provide a working example of this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stopPropagation for click event handler of each modal.

I agree with other answer, that there should be only one modal per whole page, which can be shown and hidden.

Regarding your comment: In order to "attach to given table cell" you should parameterize your one and only instance of modal window.

```js
months = ["Jan", "Feb"];
currentMonth = 0;
currentYear = 2035;

$('td').on('click', function(e) {

  $('td').removeClass("selectedDate");
  $(this).addClass("selectedDate");
  var n = $(this).find('.date').text(); //selects the date input for the cell.
  let ordN = n + (n > 0 ? ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'][(n > 3 && n < 21) || n % 10 > 3 ? 0 : n % 10] : '');

  let modal = $('#modalTemplate').clone(true);
  $(this).append(modal);
  let modalId = `${months[currentMonth]}-${n}-${currentYear}`;
  modal.attr('id', `${modalId}`);


  modal.find('#modalHeader').text(`${months[currentMonth]} ${ordN} ${currentYear}`);

  modal.show();
  modal.on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="data" /></td>
    <td><input class="data" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="data" /></td>
    <td><input class="data" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<div class="modal" id="modalTemplate">
  <span id="modalHeader"></span> 
  Hello Modal
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Note, that I also changed .modal class to #modalTemplate id. Otherwise with each click 2^(n-1) modal are inserted, where n is number of click.

Comment: Ah I understand, a bunch of Modals were getting inserted because I was grabbing all of the modals via class. Got it ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have misunderstood how modals are supposed to be used.

In my experience, they should always be at the bottom of the page (otherwise you might get all kinds of problems with positions/sizes, the backdrop not working and so on).

So, don't append the modal to the td. Just put it at the bottom of the page, and call $(".modal").modal('show');

I don't understand why you're cloning the modal.
I'm assuming it might be because you want the modal to be "reset" after each use.
If that's the case, just use a single modal. But refresh/inject the modal content before opening the modal. There are multiple techniques for this. Some simple javascript might do it, it can be solved by templating, or in some cases by loading the modal content through ajax. It all depends.

For instance, you might do something like this

```
<div class="my-modal-content d-none">[put you modal content html here]</div>

<div class="modal my-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
      ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
       ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then you might use a script like this

```
$('td').on('click', function(e) {
    var modalContentHtml = $(".my-modal-content").html();
    $(".my-modal .modal-body").html(modalContentHtml);

    // Do event binding to the modal content if necessary

    $(".my-modal").modal('show');

}
```

Comment: My thought process was that when the user clicks on a td cell (I'm making a calendar) a modal would pop up to fill out with things they did that day which they could jot down. I cloned an "empty" modal (one that hasn't been filled out) appended it to the td cell so that that modal would be for that specific date.

Comment: After filling it out should modal disappear or stay in table cell forever and ever?

Comment: Hmm as it is now it would stay in the cell forever. Once I start getting into PHP and server side coding, ideally the modal for that specific date would be saved in a server/database which can be called on whenever.